# How to retrieve excel cell formatting properties in app-for-office add-in

Tags: apps-for-office

I'm starting to play around with apps for office - specifically working on a task-pane app for excel that needs to retrieve cell formatting properties from a range.

It is possible to set properties in a bound table with

```
bindingObj.setFormatsAsync(cellFormat [,options] , callback);
```

but an equivalent getFormatsAsync() doesn't appear to exist. Anybody know how to do this?